# Create a Maven project in Intellij IDEA 12 but alway in the "Loading archetype list "page

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I created a Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA 12, finished the project name and pressed “next”，and now it shows GroupId，ArtifactId and Version. But Maven archetypes don't appear. It says

> Loading archetype list....

I can press the “finish” but the project that created is not a web project.

Has anyone ever faced this situation?

Comment: same problem with IDEA version 13

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ new project - maven archetype list empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893134/intellij-new-project-maven-archetype-list-empty)

Answer (score 29):

You can try to delete the files under {User_Home}/.IntelliJIdea{Version}/system/Maven/Indices
and then restart your idea, this should work.

Comment: yes, it did the trick for me! there is the list of maven archetypes immediately! and i did "invalidate caches and restart" btw

Comment: On OSX, the directory is ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea15/Maven/Indices

Comment: With 2016.3 on OSX, same logic, ~/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2016.3/Maven/Indices

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if the question is still actual, but maybe you need to update maven's repositories index at first?

Settings->Maven->Repositories - select maven's Central repo (if it's there; otherwise you should add it (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)) and press Update button. This will take some time (it's about 270MB to download and parse for now). After that you'll have all the maven's Central index available locally together with an archetypes list.

If there's still a problem with *Loading* after things done, you may want to specify Maven->Importing: *"VM options for importer"* to `-Xmx1024m` (default is `-Xmx512m` and it's not enough).