# IntelliJ new project - maven archetype list empty

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, intellij-14

When creating *IntelliJ → New Project → Maven*, the archetype list is blank and does not populate no matter how long the amount of time elapsed. The "Loading archetype list..." continues but does not appear to do much. Any suggestions?

[image]

Info from `mvn -v`:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (NON-CANONICAL_2014-12-25T17:13:28_root; 2014-12-25T05:13:28-08:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.17.6-1-arch", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

IntelliJ IDEA Professional 14.0.2

Comment: For me, this worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421103/create-a-maven-project-in-intellij-idea-12-but-alway-in-the-loading-archetype-l

Comment: Sometimes, **just be patient**. I have seen it take a full minute or more to populate. There are definitely bugs that bite, but do not jump to that conclusion until after waiting a few minutes.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Maven's JRE is running out of memory.

Under *Build → Build Tools → Maven → Importing*, set *VM options for importer* to `-Xmx1024m` (the default vaule `-Xmx512m` is too low).

Comment: SO is incredible.  I had this problem just today with IntelliJ 15; a Google search found this answer and I'm sorted.  Thank you!

Comment: I am using Intellij 15.0.3 and here, there is no Build Tools under Build. Instead, I followed Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing and change the value, as you said and worked +1.

Comment: Is there a bug report for this issue?

Comment: The answer is true on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2 on Mac OS X El Captain (10.11.6)

Comment: answer works for Intellij IDEA 2016.2 on ubuntu 16.04  also

Comment: Working ok on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 on various tested *nix systems.

Comment: I had to go up to -Xmx2048m as 1024 was no longer enough.

Comment: FYI, on IntelliJ 2017.1 the default for that setting is 768m.

Comment: I'm on IntelliJ 2017.1.4 that had 768 default but I still just kept seeing the spinner. Upping the setting to 1024 worked for me.

Comment: appropriate for IntelliJ 2017.3

Answer (score 24):

## Switch Java runtimes

I had the same problem. My solution was, change the JRE in *Settings → Maven → Importing → JDK for Importer*. Switch from "Internal JRE" to "External JRE".

```
[  70091]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:134)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:105)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:181)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.getArchetypes(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:168)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:165)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getArchetypes(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:165)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.getArchetypes(MavenIndicesManager.java:308)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenArchetypesStep$6.run(MavenArchetypesStep.java:239)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:201)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermBuffer.toTerm(TermBuffer.java:122)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermEnum.term(SegmentTermEnum.java:167)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMergeInfo.next(SegmentMergeInfo.java:66)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.MultiSegmentReader$MultiTermEnum.next(MultiSegmentReader.java:494)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$10.createValue(FieldCacheImpl.java:389)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl.getStringIndex(FieldCacheImpl.java:351)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.comparatorString(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:415)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue$1.createValue(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:206)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.getCachedComparator(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:167)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.<init>(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:55)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldDocCollector.<init>(TopFieldDocCollector.java:43)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:121)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.getMoreDocs(Hits.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.<init>(Hits.java:90)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultSearchEngine.searchFlat(DefaultSearchEngine.java:179)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultSearchEngine.searchFlatPaged(DefaultSearchEngine.java:99)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultSearchEngine.searchFlatPaged(DefaultSearchEngine.java:77)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultNexusIndexer.searchFlat(DefaultNexusIndexer.java:386)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.archetype.NexusArchetypeDataSource.getArchetypeCatalog(NexusArchetypeDataSource.java:55)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.doCollectArchetypes(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:324)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.getArchetypes(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:317)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
[  70094]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2  Build #IU-139.659.2 
[  70094]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_25 
[  70094]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[  70094]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[  70094]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Linux 
[  70094]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: CloseProject 

^C
saschajostock@euerEhren:~/lib/Programme/idea-IU-139.225.3/bin$ ./idea.sh 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: alter_external_table_clauses
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: records_per_block_clause
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: ref_attribute
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: physical_properties
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: redo_logfile_spec
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: row_movement_clause
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: hash_subpartition_quantity
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: primary_operator
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: xml_type_column_properties
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: parameter_types
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: partition_value
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: lob_partition_storage
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: create_cluster
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: index_attributes
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: parameter_type
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: return_type
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: scn_value
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: move_table_clause
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: data_item
DEBUG - [ORACLE-SQL] undefined element type: create_index_statement

[  12601]   WARN - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - Die Adresse wird bereits verwendet 
java.net.BindException: Die Adresse wird bereits verwendet
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:512)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1121)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeBindNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:108)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeBind(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:214)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:233)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:943)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:212)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:340)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:356)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:834)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
[  13050]   WARN - .ExternalResourceManagerExImpl - Cannot find standard resource. filename:/META-INF/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd class=class com.intellij.javaee.ResourceRegistrarImpl, classLoader:null 
[ 135618]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:134)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1$1.compute(RemoteUtil.java:105)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:181)
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$2$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.getArchetypes(Unknown Source)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:168)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:165)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getArchetypes(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:165)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.getArchetypes(MavenIndicesManager.java:308)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenArchetypesStep$6.run(MavenArchetypesStep.java:239)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$10.createValue(FieldCacheImpl.java:402)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl.getStringIndex(FieldCacheImpl.java:351)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.comparatorString(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:415)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue$1.createValue(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:206)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl$Cache.get(FieldCacheImpl.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.getCachedComparator(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:167)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.FieldSortedHitQueue.<init>(FieldSortedHitQueue.java:55)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.TopFieldDocCollector.<init>(TopFieldDocCollector.java:43)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:121)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.getMoreDocs(Hits.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Hits.<init>(Hits.java:90)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultSearchEngine.searchFlat(DefaultSearchEngine.java:179)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultSearchEngine.searchFlatPaged(DefaultSearchEngine.java:99)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultSearchEngine.searchFlatPaged(DefaultSearchEngine.java:77)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultNexusIndexer.searchFlat(DefaultNexusIndexer.java:386)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.index.archetype.NexusArchetypeDataSource.getArchetypeCatalog(NexusArchetypeDataSource.java:55)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.doCollectArchetypes(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:324)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.getArchetypes(Maven3ServerIndexerImpl.java:317)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
[ 135620]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2  Build #IU-139.659.2 
[ 135620]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_25 
[ 135620]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[ 135620]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[ 135620]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Linux 
[ 135620]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: CloseProject
```

Comment: In IntelliJ 14 is: `Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Maven → Importing → JDK for Importer`

Comment: Worked. But why? What is the external JRE doing which the internal JRE isn't or vice versa?

Comment: This ended up being the only solution that worked for me. It didn't matter how much I increased my memory setting. Changing to the External JRE did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

Changing the Settings->Maven->Importing->JDK for importer selection did not work for me.  But clearing the "-Xmx512m" value that was in Settings->Maven->Importing->VM options for importer did.  After clearing that value and saving the settings, the Maven archetype list for New Module loaded immediately in IntelliJ IDEA Professional 14.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

The max memory did the trick for me as well, IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.2.4

Here's a screenshot of the settings if it helps:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar problem. After looking at IDE log, I have figured out it was not able to connect the localhost. It was showing below exception :

```
2016-11-30 13:47:54,193 [10832638]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Cannot reconnect. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getArchetypes(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:175)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.getArchetypes(MavenIndicesManager.java:310)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenArchetypesStep.lambda$updateArchetypesList$2(MavenArchetypesStep.java:237)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:173)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$4.create(MavenServerManager.java:527)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$4.create(MavenServerManager.java:523)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:175)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.lambda$acquire$2(RemoteProcessSupport.java:258)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:226)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:256)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:170)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 26 more
```

I have found the solution mentioned in the below link which has worked for me
[Unable to import Maven project into IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701347/unable-to-import-maven-project-into-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 2):

Helped two changes:

1. *Clearing the field*: Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> **VM options for importer** (just make this field empty)
2. *Changing the option* Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> **JDK for importer** to "1.8 (java version "1.8........etc.)

Answer (score 1):

File -> Settings -> Type Maven in the search box and sub menu of Maven Importing has both the options. IntelliJ 2016.3.2

The setting that worked for me are combination of

```
1. "JDK for importer" to External(my Installed JDK) and
2. "VM option for importer" to a higher value -Xmx1536m
```

But crucial was as stated by Sascha Jostock

[image: Maven settings for Archetype]

After restart I needed to increase "VM option for importer" to a higher value -Xmx1792m. I find it stupid!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try change VM options for importer: -Xmx2048M Settings -> Maven -> Importing. Tested on IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4, JRE 1.8.0_111

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un8S3t1N4FY

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had solve this.

'$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java' file is not have  permission of run.

(http://1004lucifer.blogspot.kr/2015/08/intellij-loading-archetype-list.html)

Answer (score -1):

After checking the idea.log under ~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea13/, I found there was an excpetion being thrown Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. The root cause was my /etc/hosts file got corrupted somehow and the localhost ip was updated to some garbage value. After changing the localhost mapping to 127.0.0.1, my problem got resolved