# IntelliJ maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to create project/module from archetype, but ide can't find any archetypes:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/02cd9e04337001eafa0b107f7a00b1af.png]

I have read this question [IntelliJ new project - maven archetype list empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893134/intellij-new-project-maven-archetype-list-empty) my problem is exactly same, but i tried all sollution others posted but nothing helped me.

Using windows 7, ultimate version.

Comment: Does it show anything in the error log? (Help -> Show log)

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings -> Maven -> Importing and change the value from -Xmx512m to -Xmx1512m.